# How to access Storage from SD card connected via OTG

Tags: android

I try to read and change an textfile on the external storage SD card. To make the example more easy I already inserted the content URI I get from the File Chooser.

I run the app on an Nexus 5X with Android 7 (SDK 24). The minSdkVersion is set to 19 and the targetSdkVersion is 23.

```
package de.cowabuja.androiduriaccess;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String uriString = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FAny%2Dir%2FtheFile.txt";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

        getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

Here the Log:

```
...
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: de.cowabuja.androiduriaccess, PID: 2972
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.cowabuja.androiduriaccess/de.cowabuja.androiduriaccess.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10132 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FAny%2FDir%2FtheFile.txt
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10132 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FAny%2FDir%2theFile.txt
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.grantUriPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:4808)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.grantUriPermission(ContextImpl.java:1655)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.grantUriPermission(ContextWrapper.java:712)
                      at de.cowabuja.androiduriaccess.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
...
```

I try to call grantUriPermission because I try to solve the exception I did get before:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading de.cowabuja.androidaccess uri   content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FAny%2Dir%2FtheFile.txt from pid=1399, uid=10350 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.cowabuja.androiduriaccess">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assemble a `Uri` to a third-party provider like that and expect it to work. That provider has not granted you permission to work with that content. At most, it *previously* gave you *temporary* access to the content, but those rights died when your process died.

Either:

- Move the file to one of the locations where you have filesystem access on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html): `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`. If those methods (on `Context`) return 2+ entries, the second and subsequent ones are directories on removable storage that you can use. You can then use normal Java file I/O (e.g., `File`, `FileInputStream`).
- Use [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) to ask the user to choose a file to work with. The user may elect to choose one on removable storage, or not, as it is the user's device and the user's files. You would then [use the `Uri` with `ContentResolver`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), via methods like `openInputStream()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I have to use the Storage Access Framework because the user should be able to connect the SD card via USB OTG Card Reader.

Comment: I tried this: `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` but than i get the following exception: `requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`

As far as i understand put MANAGE_DOCUMENTS as permission in the AndroidManifest.xml will not solve the problem. So what can I do to get access?

Comment: @cowabunga1984: Use [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) to allow the user to *choose a piece of content*. You will then be given a `Uri` that you can use.

Comment: OK, I can try this. But is it possible than to copy another folder into the same folder the selected file is stored in?

Comment: @cowabunga1984: Only if the user grants you access via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` (again, part of the Storage Access Framework).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. To solve my problems with cordova and accessing Data on the SD Card I created a Cordova Plugin to copy the data from any source to the internal App Storage and back:
https://github.com/uklawitter/cordova-plugin-android-copytree